# Dependency specified was Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc >= 6.0.0-beta6 but ended up with Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In VS 2015, after upgrading NuGet packages I get the following warning:

> Dependency specified was Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc >= 6.0.0-beta6 but ended
>   up with Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta5.

What does this mean?

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the newly upgraded package had not been restored to my system. I had to manually restore the packages by righting clicking on the project and choosing Restore.

Why would they not restore on the build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restore doesn't happen on build. It happens when dependencies change (project.json is saved or a manual restore happens). Building needs to happen way more often than changing dependencies so coupling the two things isn't really a great idea. Also because the entire dependency graph needs to be checked against your configured feeds, restore might be a slow operation. So it's best not to slow the build down.

FYI: You should never get an error like that (saying that beta6 was specified and beta6 was resovled. This is a bug see https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2402)